# Noob filter: How do I refer to a string that is passed to my Ruby on Rails method from Flex as a HTTPService?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, flex4

EDIT:

Got too confusing with so many different edits, so this is where I'm currently at.

I have a HTTPService in my Flex 4 app defined as follows:

```
<s:HTTPService id="getUserDetails" url="http://localhost:3000/users/getDetails" method="GET"/>
```

I call this service like this (note: I've checked the network monitor in Flash Builder 4 and the userNameLookup variable is sent correctly):

```
var userNameLookup:String;
userNameLookup = calleeInput.text;
getUserDetails.send(userNameLookup);
```

And finally, this is the Ruby on Rails method:

```
def getDetails
  @user = User.find_by_username(:userNameLookup)
  render :xml => @user
end
```

This is the error message in the log:

> Processing UsersController#getDetails
>   (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-27 19:24:23)
>   [GET]   User Load (0.2ms)   SELECT *
>   FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username"
>   = '--- :userNameLookup ') LIMIT 1
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing
>   template users/getDetails.erb in view
>   path app/views):
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:33:in
>   `getDetails'
>
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:32:in`
>   getDetails'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in
>   `service'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in`
>   run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in
>   `start_thread'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in`
>   start'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in
>   `start_thread'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in`
>   start'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in
>   `each'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in`
>   start'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in
>   `start'
>
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in`
>   start'

So it appears that the userNameLookup parameter isn't being referred to correctly?
Just a thought, but does it matter that I've set the HTTPService to GET even though it is posting something?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that already. I pasted it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller action methods should be implemented without parameters. The parameters can be inferred from the request parameters.

Try this:

```
def getDetails
  @user = User.first(:conditions => {:username => params[:lookupUsername]})
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :xml => @user }
  end
end
```

In the code above I have used `lookupUsername` as the query parameter. Change that to the actual name sent by your flex client.

**Edit 1**

You need explicit xml format handler to return the result as XML. Apart from this, it looks like `lookupUsername` parameter is empty in your invocations. Is it possible that the query parameter is named something else? You can get the name of the query parameter by looking at the log file. Your log file should show an entry like this:

```
Processing xxxxController#getDetails (for 127.xxx at 2010-04-15 10:27:21) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"getDetails", "controller"=>"xxxx", 
              "lookupUsername" => "bob"}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I tried doing it this way, but I'm still getting the error (which I've pasted into the original question above).

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: I've updated as per your instruction, and I'm no longer getting the ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)) error. But I am getting a new error. I'll post my updated code and the console error above. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: Updated the question to remove all the old stuff. As I mention up there, you're right, the query parameter isn't being referred to correctly? I've posted the log up there. I'll add your XML suggestion in a bit! I really appreciate all your help, thanks a million.